# Monodroid and resx localisation does not work

Tags: localization, xamarin.android, resx

I have a monodroid application that uses a .net library that contains normal .resx localisation. So i have to files CoreResources.resx and CoreResources.de-DE.resx

However the program always uses the default one (CoreResources = english)

Did anybody face the same problem ?

Comment: Sorry, support for localized resources is missing; bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a parser that takes the resx file and converts it to the files expected in monodroid. Works perfectly.